# Why is it no slower to SELECT into a temp table then MERGE than it is just to MERGE from the source query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

Here's a MERGE using the results of a table-valued function:

```
MERGE
    Table1 d
USING
    dbo.tvf_Table1(@StartDate, @EndDate) s ON d.ID = s.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET Dest1 = Src1, Dest2 = Src2, Dest3 = Src3
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
    VALUES(ID, Src1, Src2, Src3);
```

In my environment, it took about 30 seconds (average over three runs).

Here's the same MERGE, but this time putting the function results in a temp table first:

```
SELECT
    *
INTO
    #Temp1
FROM
    dbo.tvf_Table1(@StartDate, @EndDate)

MERGE
    Table1 d
USING
    #Temp1 s ON d.ID = s.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET Dest1 = Src1, Dest2 = Src2, Dest3 = Src3
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
    VALUES(ID, Src1, Src2, Src3);

DROP TABLE #Temp1
```

It took about 31 seconds (average over three runs).

In fact, a run of 54 MERGEs like the above was about four minutes quicker with temp tables than without.

Accepting that this is hardly scientific, I would have expected the addition of the temp table step to slow the query significantly.  After all, the data is moving from A to B and then from B to C, instead of straight from A to C.

What goes on behind the scenes that might cause this?

Comment: Are you running the entire script (meaning, the insert to the temp table as well as the merge), or just the merge? because if it's just the merge, it's easy to understand why it's faster...

Comment: The entire script together, creating the table, running the merge and dropping the table in one go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that the amount of data put into the temp table isn't too large, the server should be able to keep it all in memory and not have to spill it out to disk. As such, `B` in your `A` -> `B`, `B` -> `C` is exceptionally cheap to access compared to `C` (and possibly `A`). You normally expect I/O costs to swamp most others in straightforward queries.

In the grand scheme of things, I'd still prefer the single `MERGE` if it's performing adequately enough. Don't try to help SQL Server out by breaking up the task into a series of subtasks - that's a job for the optimizer, and whilst it may not always pick an optimal plan, it will usually pick one that's good enough.

Comment: Thanks for this well-worded and easy-to-understand answer.  The other has more upvotes, but for me this provides a more comprehensive explanation.  The advice is helpful too.

Answer (score 2):

Temporary tables give the optimizer more information for optimization than a table-valued function.

I can appreciate that you expect the overhead for writing to the table to slow things down overall.  However, the rest of the merge query also needs to be optimized, and knowing the exact size of the table helps the optimizer improve the overall plan.